# Django: ImportError cannot import name 'Github'

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am getting this error `importerror cannot import name 'Github' django` when run `python manage.py runserver` command in windows 10.

I am using: Django=2.2.5, django-github=0.1.2, django-uuslug=1.1.9, httplib2=0.13.1, python-slugify=3.0.3, pytz=2019.2, sqlparse=0.3.0, text-unicode=1.2

Someone please help me.

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: from github import Github as gh

Comment: I cannot find proper documentation for django-github. Maybe use PyGithub?

Comment: Do you have to use django-github? It's not maintained anymore, the [homepage](http://github.com/coleifer/django-github/tree/master) leads to a 404 page and the only release was way back in 2010 (which does not seem to install anything).

Comment: Yes. It is PyGithub.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solve this problem by importing PyGithub library. Thanks to all.